# System folder Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have an application running with Codeigniter, its name is SAF.

folder structure:

```
/SAF/index.php
/SAF/application/
/SAF/system/
```

Now, i'm going to develop other application that going to use at folder structure:

```
/BOL/index.php/
/BOL/application/
```

So, can I alter the $system_path variable of index.php in BOL structure to i'll use the system folder of SAF application?

```
$system_path = '../SAF/system';
```

Are there any problem in this?

Comment: I think it should work. Nevertheless, you may want to check this link for further information on running mutliple applications on one CI instance: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Multiple_Applications/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will work, but unless your BOL application explicitly depends on SAF, I recommend moving system out of both

```
/system/
/SAF/...
/BOL/...
```

This is how I used to do it and this way the content of each directory is specific only to its own application (it avoids someone messing with /SAF/system without taking into account the fact that his changes will affect BOL as well).

Answer (score 0):

No, that should work perfectly.